# Combine Rewrite conditions in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many rewrite rules and conditions in my .htaccess as follows

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api.php -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api_1.php -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api_2.php -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api_3.php -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api_4.php -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]
```

The above conditions cache all urls contains "limit" word in the url of scripts/api.php followed by query string like '&' in urls. I need to add more apis like these, So is there a way to combine all these conditions and cache all urls contains **scripts/api**

Like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  "limit"
RewriteRule scripts/api* -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]
```

I dont thik above condtion is correct one, can anyone suggest me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite rule accepts a regular expression as the first parameter, not a wildcard string pattern.

This probably is what you are looking for instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} limit
RewriteRule ^/?scripts/api(_\d+)?\.php$ -  [E=Cache-Control:max-age=3600]
```

It probably also would make sense to use a more precise pattern in the condition... For example to prevent other HTTP GET arguments to interfere in an unexpected manner, things like for example `...&otherArg=mylimit&...` which probably is *not* what you want to accept as `limit`...

Comment: Thank you for your response, Which one should i use **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "limit"** or **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} limit**. Btw does the rule RewriteRule scripts/api(_\d+)?\.php also applies to api.php & api_10.php?

Comment: Btw **RewriteRule scripts/api(_\d+)?\.php** is not working. Please check and make correction.

Comment: `"limit"` or `limit` is irrelevant in this case. The pattern is correct, I can't say why it does not match. You will have to to start debugging, I suggest you enable rewrite logging to learn what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. Consult the official apache documentation for the rewriting module to learn how to enable that.

Comment: Do the above condition can work for 
http://testdomain.com/scripts/api_20.php?category=10&action=previews&limit=48

Comment: It certainly does. If it gets applied at all which depends on your setup which I do not know.